# Image error when convert HTML to PDF in c#

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

I'm using `'wnvhtmltopdf'` to convert `HTML` file to `PDF`. but Im facing a problem that the imags in the html file doesn't appear in the in the `PDF` file.
any idea to resolve the problem ?

if we think out of the box, is there another idea to make to convert operation ?